# Есть ли разница между объявлением переменной в цикле и за пределами цикла?

Tags: java

Есть ли разница, в объявлении переменной за пределами цикла:

```
int val = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        val++;
    }
}
```

И в цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        val++;
    }
}
```

Значение переменной val на выходе будет разным - это понятно. Но вопрос в том, влияет ли это на производительность. Обрабатывает ли это компилятор.

Я прогонял тесты с большим количеством итераций, по времени разницы не было. Но по логике вроде как должна была быть. Компилятор оптимизировал код?

Comment: смотря как дальше используется эта переменная

Comment: А если никак не используется. Вопрос в том, инициализируется ли она каждый раз при входе в цикл и влияет ли это как-нибудь на производительность, когда таких переменных много, когда мы работает, например с видео или звуком? Или это решается на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Тогда Дополните вопрос, Чтобы было понятно что конкретно вас интересует

Comment: "влияет ли это на производительность" - ничтожно. Это экономия на спичках. Лучше пишите понятный код и оптимизируйте там где это действительно нужно (по результатам профилирования).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор имеет полное право, код

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        val++;
    }
}
```

превратить в

```
int val;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    val = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        val++;
    }
}
```

и насколько я знаю он так и делает, в результате получается одно лишнее присвоение, что мало сказывается на производительности.

**P.S.** Вообще можно декомпилировать сгенеренный код и посмотреть, благо в какой-нибудь Идеа это делается легко и просто.

Comment: Знаю, но я использую Netbeans. Там не нашел.

Comment: Есть же и отдельные декмопиляторы (JAD, например) - http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad  Там в командной строке нужно просто вызывать команду

Answer (score 7):

Да, разница есть и заключается она в следующем:

1. Область видимости: в первом случае, переменная `val` видна как внутри циклов, так и извне, во втором – видна только внутри цикла (циклов) и не видна извне.
2. Логика работы кода: в первом случае, на каждой итерации цикла переменная `val` инкрементируется и итоговое значение будет `100`, во втором случае, на каждой итерации внешнего цикла, переменная `val` сбрасывается в ноль.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере есть, причем существенная. В первом случае (объявлении вне цикла), значение переменной по итогу будет равно 100. Во втором случае - 10.

Вобще разница в месте объявления переменной в том, что в некоторых случая она может выпадать из области видимости или вовсе не входить в нее.